# How to get the child data along with the parent writer data in laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have four tables,

```
      user              writer            blog                                    likes

   id   name          id   name         id   writer_id  content                 user_id    blog_id
   1     aa            1    cc          1       1        lorem                     1          2
   2     bb            2    dd          2       1        lorem ipsum               1          3  
                                        3       2        lorem ipsum               2          2
```

I am having the `user id = 2`  and now i have to get the `blog writer data`. I need the result to be in this form,

```
data: {
  'blog': {
      'id':2,
      'writer_id': 1,
      'content': 'lorem ipsum'
  },
  'writer':{
      'id':2,
      'name':'dd'
  }
}
```

I write this relation in the `likes model` but it is not working for me.

```
public function writer()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Writer', 'App\Blog', 'writer_id', 'id', 'id', 'id');
    }
```

How can i write a eloquent relation to display data like above?

Comment: Please follow laravel `eloquent-relationships` -  https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: please post your code.. what have tried so far..

Comment: I updated my code @Bhoomi Patel. Please correct

Answer (score 0):

I modified my relation little bit and it is worked for me

```
  public function writer()
        {
            return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Writer', 'App\Blog', 'id', 'id', 'blog_id', 'id');
        }
```

Here in the relation, the first two parameters indicates the models and the `third parameter id indicates id in the blog table`, `fourth id indicates the id in writer table` respectively.